# How to mark inheritance of an object in JSON?

Tags: c++, json, inheritance, format

I'm about to design a simple data format in JSON which will serialize the configuration data of some slightly different machine types. The data format should support inheritance - if only one (or some few) parameters are changed in the "InheritedObject" I can mainly use the parameters of the "BaseObject".
My first idea to do this is shown in the following code snippet:

```
{
    "BaseObject":
    {
        "Description": "some text",
        "Type": "4",
        "Value": 0.33
    },

    "InheritedObject":
    {
        "Parent": "BaseObject",
        "Element_3": 11
    }
}
```

I have a least three use cases:

- Read from JSON (if I use "InheritedObject" I want to get all elements from Inherited Object plus the element from BaseOjbect not overwritten in InheritedObject")
- Write to JSON ((auto?)compare the differences between "BaseObject" and "InheritedObject" an write the diffences to the "InheritedObject")
- Change of a parameter in the base class should automatically change the parameter in the inherited object, too.

I think this should work, but it needs some extra work when reading and writing JSON.

Is there a "built in" functionality or at least good support to do this in JSON? If so, which JSON library for C++ does support it (JsonCpp, JSON Spirit) ? Or is there a best practice way to implement this functionality from scratch. Or is there good support for this task in XML or YAML (or anything else) - I'm not absolutely fixed to JSON yet?

Comment: For anyone looking here for similar solutions: a deserializer for such JSON structure is implemented in Cataclysm Dark Days Ahead game (open-source, C++). Found this while searching for a similar deserializer in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most serialization tools/libraries I am aware of do not use this approach, but store the class and all of the instances data into one JSON object. I am not sure why you would want this in the first place, since some normally quite simple operations (*How many objects [of type X] are there?*) can get quite complicated and slow to compute (simple storage: just the number of JSON objects, done. Your approach with "stored inheritance": Well, load everything, resolve inherited data 'references' etc.).

I don't quite see the need to separate base data and inherited class data, since you can just ignore unknown attributes when reading data (in contrast to handling real C++ objects). So I wouldn't recommend to make it this complicated, just store all object data in one JSON object. You can't have duplicate attributes in C++, either, if that was your reason.

If you're thinking about storage size, then it's very likely not worth the effort. Except if you're storing millions of objects, but then a text format with the verbosity of JSON isn't the tool of choice anyway. In that case go for a binary format like boost.serialization, QDataStream or similar.

Comment: What would you do in the following case: BO (BaseObject) has a parameter named "par". This parameter is overwritten in IO_1 (InheritedObject_1), but left unchanged in IO_2. Now I change par in BO. par should be changed in IO_2, but leaved unchanged in IO_1. What is your solution without inheritance?

Comment: I think you're messing up classes, inheritance and class instances. You don't want to store classes, do you? Back to the case: Any object in C++ can only have one value and one value only for each attribute it has, regardless of where the attribute was declared. So the answer is: "No, such construction does not exist. Either I change it in IO_1 and IO_2 is part of inheritance hierachy, then par is changed everywhere in the instance, or IO_2 is not part of it, then I can't access props of IO_1 instance from IO_2"

Comment: As I told in the question is's a data format for machine parameters. I don't want to serialize classes. I want to represent a parameter set of one single machine as an object. What I want to use is redefinition (which is possible in C++ only for classes not for objects - but as already said it should be used for different machines neither software classes nor software object.